# 4-bit BCD to 7-segment

Tags: c, scanf

I'm making a 4-bit BCD decoder to **7-segment** display in C.

After the output is displayed I ask if the user wants to input again. I can display the desired output and I can exit the program when I don't want to input again.

The problem is when I want to input again it doesn't stop to ask for my input and prints the previous input.

This is the output:

```
This program displays the decimal equivalent of a
4-bit binary-coded decimal input on a 7-segment LED Display.

Please enter a 4-bit binary-coded decimal: 1000
You've entered 1000.

The decimal equivalent is 8.

              _
             |_|
LED Display: |_|


Would you like to input another 4-bit BCD?
Enter [1] if yes or [0] if no. 1
Please enter a 4-bit binary-coded decimal: You've entered 1000.

The decimal equivalent is 8.

              _
             |_|
LED Display: |_|


Would you like to input another 4-bit BCD?
Enter [1] if yes or [0] if no.
```

This is my code:

```
int main() {
    int i, dec, retry = 1; //declare integers i ,dec, and retry
    int bit[4]; //declare integer array with 4 elements
    unsigned char input[5]; //declare string with 5 elements

    printf("This program displays the decimal equivalent of a\n 4-bit binary-coded decimal input on a 7-segment LED Display.\n\n");

    do {         
        printf("Please enter a 4-bit binary-coded decimal: "); //instructs user to enter 4-bit bcd
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", input); //read string
        printf("You've entered %s.\n\n", input); //shows the 4-bit bcd input 

        for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
            bit[i] = input[i] - '0';
        }

        dec = bit[0]*8 + bit[1]*4 +bit[2]*2 + bit[3];
        printf("The decimal equivalent is %d.\n\n", dec); //shows decimal equivalent

        switch (dec) { //displays 7-segment display depending on the value of dec
            case 0:
                printf("              _ \n             | |\nLED Display: |_|\n");     
                break;
           ...
        }
        printf("\n\nWould you like to input another 4-bit BCD?\nEnter [1] if yes or [0] if no. ");
        scanf("%d", &retry); 
    }
    while (retry == 1);   
}
```

I also encounter the same problem when using `fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);` instead of `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", input);`

Comment: The input `1\n` given in order to go on, makes the following `scanf()` return without any value scanf'd. Checking its return value you would find the second time is 0, so the variable isnot updated and the previous value is used.

Comment: I think when you enter 1 for example then `\n` will be in the input buffer and when the iteration will start over `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", input);` will fail since the format string say it should start with a non white space char.

Comment: @RaymondOh , in order to improve the question you should add the output as text instead of in image form.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I will take note of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the input `1\n` is  given in order to go on withe next *7 segment number*, only `1` is captured by `scanf()` and `\n` is left tho the followong one.

But the format `%[^\n]` tells `scanf()` to NOT match any input starting with a `\n`, so the leftover makes the following it return without any value scanf'd. Checking its return value you would find that the second time is 0, so the variable is not updated and that's why the previous value is used.

In order to fix it, since you need `%[^\n]` in to trim the input (you expect only digits), just add a space before current input format:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", input);
```

in this way any *whitespace character* (all characters for which [isspace()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) returns true, including `'\n'`, `' '`, and`'\t'`) is consumed.

Note that adding

```
fflush(stdin);
```

before your first `scanf()` is *Undefined Behavior* for the standard C. In some environments it works, **but this solution should be avoided as, to say the least, it makes the code non-portable**!

**Note:** you have the same behavior with `fgets()` because it reads until a `\n` is found, and like it happened before with `scanf`, that's exactly the character remaining from the previous user input insertion.

---

### Suggestions on how to check your input

Instead of using `%[^\n]` format, I suggest a different approach in order to check your input:

```
while( 1 )
{
    printf("Please enter a 4-bit binary-coded decimal: "); //instructs user to enter 4-bit bcd
    scanf(" %4s", input); //read string

    if( validateBinaryInput( input, 4 ) == 0 )
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Wrong input!\n" );
    }
}
```

With `scanf(" %4s", input);` you make sure to capture exactly four characters, and to store them within `input` array. The loop makes sure that whenever the input is not valid the input sequence is repeate. The input validity can be checked with `validateBinaryInput()` function. Please find below an implementation example:

```
/* Returns 0 on success, -1 on failure */
int validateBinaryInput( unsigned char *input, size_t len )
{
    int ret = 0;

    if( !input )
    {
        ret = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for( i=0; i<len; i++ )
        {
            if( input[i] != '0' && input[i] != '1' )
                ret = -1;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Not only it makes sure that every inserted character is a digit, but it verifies that it is a *binary digit*. In this way you avoid strange behaviors that would occur inserting an input such as `5`: your assignment of

```
dec = bit[0]*8 + bit[1]*4 +bit[2]*2 + bit[3];
```

would result in the value **5**, and the corresponding 7-segments digit would be printed even if the input wasn't a valid binary word.

Comment: I tried removing it so I'm left with this: scanf("%%*c", input); but the program instantly closes now. Someone suggested adding a space in front and it worked. What will happen if I use fgets instead of scanf?

Comment: @RaymondOh 
I edited the answer. Also the first % needs to be removed.

Comment: Unfortunately using  scanf("%*c", input); the program just closes after inputting without displaying anything. However, using scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", input); worked.

Comment: @RaymondOh try it now. It is an alternative solution instead of just adding a whitespace in the first scanf.

Comment: No! `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior! Never flush an input stream! Just put a space before the format in the first scanf to fix it.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Well, I admit you are right. I forgot it, but in my defense I have to say that I've seen this used in many applications (probably because, though UB for the standard, many environment allow it documenting its support). I'll have to edit my answer with another solution. Putting the blank space at the beginning of printf() is not correct, because as far as I understand it is against the purpose of the %[^\n] in that scanf.

Comment: The `%[^\n]` reads a string until a newline is encountered, and then puts the newline back on the stream. If a space is present in the format and a whitespace character is not read, the space is a no-op. `fflush(stdin)` does work for Windows and Linux, but it may not work on Mac and BSD-based systems.

Comment: @RaymondOh , I've edited my answer because the _fflush(stdin)_ solution could lead to UB if you are not absolutely sure that your system documents it works without problem. It' is better to use the _leading space_ solution. PS: I added a suggestion on how to check your input.

Comment: Nice fix. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni oh wow thanks! That was actually the next thing that I was gonna implement. I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

This line right here is an issue:

```
      scanf("%[^\n]%*c", input); //read string
```

The previous `%d` only consumes whitespace before the format specifier, not after. This means that this `scanf` will read an empty string.

To fix this, add a space before so the whitespace *will* be consumed:

```
      scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", input); //read string
```